# No having binding error when required property missing in minimal api

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I am building a simple minimal api using net6. I am working with enable
I have a simple model like this:

```
public record MyModel(string Prop_1, string Prop_2);
```

I have an endpoint defined as follows:

```
builder.MapPut("/models/save",
            async (MyModel model) =>
            {
                // Do something to save the model
            });
```

The issue is that even when the record is defined in a way that MyProp_1 can not be null, if I call this endpoint  with the following body, I get an instance of MyModel with null as the value of Prop_1

{
"Prop_2": "Some value"
}

In brief: omitting a non-nullable property in the body causes, after the model binding, an instance of the model with the required property having a null value. I was expecting something like a model-binding error. Could anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: Why don't you just check if the value is null?

Comment: I think the model binding process should raise an error. Besides, this is a very simple example, but if the model has 10 properties, it is not nice to check for null values ten times.

Comment: I don't have any idea how you can manage that besides checking that manually. Maybe assign some default value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature in C# is a compiler checked semantic.  Even still you can compile and run a program with uninitialized properties, you will just get a compiler warning for it. As always you should check your inputs before using them.

**Update**

It seems like minimal api does not support model validation at all out of the box. There are some [third party solutions](https://dotnetthoughts.net/working-model-validation-in-minimal-api/) however if you want this "for free" you will have to go the old mvc or razor page route.

Comment: New, but not improved?